# Multiple ValidationSummary and RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: asp.net

I have two Validation Groups on my page, called "login" and "register".  Each group has its own ValidationSummary control and there a number of RequiredFieldValidators too.  The problem I have is that the form is validating both groups instead of just the one.

Here is the code (I have omitted a lot of HTML to simplify):

```
<div id="divRegisterBox">

  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="register" />

  <asp:TextBox ID="tbRegisterEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Required" ValidationGroup="register" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="tbRegisterEmail" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address." ValidationGroup="register" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" CssClass="errorMsg" ControlToValidate="tbRegisterEmail" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address." ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" ValidationGroup="register" />

  <asp:TextBox ID="tbRegisterPassword" name="result-password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Required" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="register" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" CssClass="errorMsg" ControlToValidate="tbRegisterPassword" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password." ValidationGroup="register" />

  <asp:Button ID="btnMobileRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnMobileRegister_Click" ValidationGroup="register" />

</div>

<div id="divLoginBox">

  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login" />

  <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" name="result-email" ID="tbResultEmail" placeholder="Required" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="tbResultEmail" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address." ValidationGroup="login" CssClass="errorMsg" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" CssClass="errorMsg" ControlToValidate="tbResultEmail" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address." ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" ValidationGroup="login" />

  <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" name="result-password" ID="tbResultPassword" placeholder="Required" TextMode="Password" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" CssClass="errorMsg" ControlToValidate="tbResultPassword" runat="server" Text="" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password." ValidationGroup="login" />

  <asp:Button ID="btnLoginMobile" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" Text="Login" OnClientClick="return MobileLoginSubmit();" ValidationGroup="login" OnClick="btnLoginMobile_Click" />

</div>
```

When I click either of the Button controls, the ValidationSummary controls show the validation messages for ALL validation controls on the page.  It is as if they were all part of the same validation group.

I have tried adding CausesValidation="true" and "false" to the Buttons but it seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

On your CodeBehind, you could do something like...

```
Page.Validate("register");
if (Page.IsValid)
  {
      //Keep calm and carry on
  }

else
   {
       foreach (BaseValidator invalidField in validators)
            {  
              //Do something with the invalid fields 
            }
    }
```

That way, you're only validating that group that you specify.

Makes sense?

Comment: A postback is not triggered, so no CodeBehind is used.  The RequiredFieldValidators seem to be working client-side.

Comment: On that note, can you wrap each area in an UpdatePanel element to isolate them from each other?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `Display="None"`.

In your `divRegisterBox` div, your validators all have `Display="None"`, but your validators in your `divLoginBox` div do not.

`Display="None"` will not display the message inline. What you are seeing when you click the login button is not that both summaries are showing, but that the same error messages are being displayed in two different ways.

Comment: I have removed the display="none" but it made no difference.

Comment: You need to add it to the validators that didn't have it, not remove it from those that did.

Comment: Ok I tried to add it to all validation controls but again had the same result.

Comment: Ok, well I copied your code as is, added Display="None" to the validators and it worked as expected. Are you 100% sure all validation messages are showing? As in...if no fields are filled in and you click a button, you see four total messages in one summary?